# Do I need a controller for every JSP that displays data?

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, dao

I'm building a Java web app that follows the MVC model.

I have a number of JSP pages that act as views for the respective objects in the DB, for example `product_details.jsp`.

I plan to use URLs like `product_details.jsp?id=123`, and since I have quite a lot of View pages, I was wondering if it was necessary to write a servlet for each of them that only retrieves data from a DAO or if there was a clean way to call a DAO from inside the JSP itself.

Would this violate the MVC model even if no controller is needed? What would be the best approach?

Comment: The best approach is to respect the MVC pattern. Otherwise you'll end up with a bunch of code in, or called from, the view, which is precisely what MVC is meant to avoid. You'll also be unable to handle errors correctly. There are plenty of MVC frameworks out there, like Spring MVC. Why don't you use that, instead of servlets, which are quite cumbersome?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a school project so I have limited freedom in what I can use. I understand anyway, I'll stick to the model, thank you.